# How do I hide all lists other than the selected list?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-lists

I'm trying to create a sortable list with jQuery UI,  My code appears to work, but I want to add a drop down to each list to set an active for the clicked list.

How do I change this so, when selected, the selected sublist should be shown and the others should be hidden?

Relevant [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lgtsfiddler/AuRe9/2/).

Relevant HTML:

```
<!doctype html>
 <html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>jQuery UI Sortable - Default functionality</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<ul id="sortable">
<li class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>
   <a href="#">Item 1</a>
            <ul class="subnav">
                <li><a href="#">Sub Item 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Sub Item 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Sub Item 3</a></li>
            </ul>

</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 3</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 4</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 5</li>

</ul>
```

Comment: do you have any example demo??

Answer (score 1):

The `.ui-sortable-helper` class is added when starting dragging a `li` element. So with this simple css you can show the subclass only when dragging the element :

```
#sortable .subnav {display: none;}
#sortable>li.ui-sortable-helper .subnav {display: block;}
```

See the [updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AuRe9/13/)